# Probability operation doubt

Tags: probability

I have an event where if that event happens I incur a benefit of **B** and cost of **C**

The event occurs with probability **p**

Therefore I can write this as: p*(B - C)

I want this net benefit to be smaller than an amount N

So I write down p*(B - C) < N

Now  to keep Benefit on one side and rest on the others, 
do you write it like this:

$$ B < \frac {N}{p} + C? $$

I guess my broader question here is if you can distribute the p of probability like I did above?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.   If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @saulspatz corrected. thanks!

Comment: You have to enclose MathJax commands in `$` signs in order for them to take effect.  `$\frac {N}{p}$` formats as $\frac {N}{p}$

Comment: Assuming that if the event doesn't happen there is no cost and no benefit, yes, what you did was acceptable.  You should read more about expected value if you want a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, but to be precise: If $p\cdot(B-C)<N$ **and** $p>0$, then $B<\tfrac Np+C$ .